# Conveniently devolop Java on my Desktop PC and testrun on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: gpio, remote, java

Is there any way to develop Java on my Desktop PC and test-run it conveniently on my RaspberryPi. I'd prefer developing on a more powerful PC, but I'd need to run it on the RaspberryPi due to developing for GPIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Set up a script on the pi to sftp the compiled java classes from your development machine and run them. Something along the lines of

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sftp mydevelopmentmachine << END
cd javadevelopment
mget *.class
END
java MyProgram
```

should do the trick. Then just run the script on your pi whenever you have recompiled the project.

It would probably be a good idea to make sure you have the same version of java on both machines.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like just the right thing :)
I'll try it out. Will first have to set-up sftp though ^^

Answer (score 0):

I perform Java development on my PC and execution on the Pi.  Since Java generates classes and classes are machine/architecture independent, I use the PC to compile to classes.  What I also do is use NFS running on the Pi to mount an NFS exported file system from my PC (If you are using Windows for your PC, Samba should also work).  This way I can compile on the PC and then immediately execute on the Pi.  This alleviates the need to copy from the PC to the PI which introduces an error step caused by "forgetting to copy".  It also speeds up the workflow.

I took the time to write up notes on this on the free book available here:

https://leanpub.com/pi